# How to add save button to action bar in android

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

How would I go about adding a save and cancel button to my action bar in android studio? 
I'm new to android development so any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: have a look at the documentation [Adding Action Buttons](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html)

Comment: ya i did already cheers

Comment: then you should be able to answer your own question ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use of **Linear Layout** will make two buttons to add in one line(i guess you are thinking about this only) if so then use linear layout in your code
add this code to your
*layouts/action_bar_save_cancel.xml*

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
  android:orientation="horizontal" >
 <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/action_bar_button_cancel"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"           
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Cancel" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/action_bar_button_ok"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"           
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Ok" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Hit correct button if this helped you**

Comment: @AndroidAnt you can.. because you are author of the post!!

Comment: Sorry!! i did it!! :)